# Modular Arithmetic Olymp Problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ is a positive integer such that divisible by $103$. If exists find all $n$ such that $2^{2n+1}=2(\mod n)$

Comment: See [Olymp](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olymp).

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution.

$2^{2n+1} = 2*2^{2n} = 2( \mod n)*2^{2n}$

Since $2( \mod n)*2^{2n} = 2( \mod n)$, this means $2^{2n} = 0(\mod n)$

Thus,  $2^{2n}|103k$, where k is real.  Since 103 does not divide 2, k can only be 0.

We try k = 0.  $n = 103k$, so $n = 0$.  Now $2^0$ is not divisible by $103k$.  Hence $k = 0$ is wrong too.  This means there is no solution.